# interface stops retrieving pages when static ip is set

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ip-address

Below is my current setup, the main ethernet connection is configured with a static ip and it's working fine. The two other interfaces are connected to different Android hotspots using DHCP. I have also configured routes so that each interface can receive/send traffic independently

Below is my fully working `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
root@poweredge:/etc/network# cat interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp1s0
#iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
iface enp1s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.212
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlx74da388c32d0
iface wlx74da388c32d0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid four
        wpa-psk fcac8bd4439859aadf1457463f47f49091acb02895bd5a28914a1fc36969c66d
        post-up ip route add default via 172.16.11.254 table wlx74da388c32d0
        post-up ip rule add from 172.16.11.107 lookup wlx74da388c32d0



auto wlx74da388c32c7
iface wlx74da388c32c7 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid one
        wpa-psk e629e0873738c638cde76ae81487effb28b0e22c309c9e163996e389a313c14c
        post-up ip route add default via 192.168.43.1 table wlx74da388c32c7
        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.43.209 lookup wlx74da388c32c7
```

I have confirmed that each interface is working independently by using the following commands

```
curl --interface wlx74da388c32c7 ifconfig.co
curl --interface wlx74da388c32d0 ifconfig.co
curl --interface enp1s0 ifconfig.co
```

Each curl command is showing the public IP address of the connection as expected. This is exactly how I want things to work.

However, I am running into issues when I setup a static IP on one of the wireless interfaces. For example when I change interface `wlx74da388c32c7` to static IP as below

```
auto wlx74da388c32c7
iface wlx74da388c32c7 inet static
        address 192.168.43.100
        netmast 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.43.1
        wpa-ssid one
        wpa-psk e629e0873738c638cde76ae81487effb28b0e22c309c9e163996e389a313c14c
        post-up ip route add default via 192.168.43.1 table wlx74da388c32c7
        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.43.100 lookup wlx74da388c32c7
```

curl just hangs when I try to get a page using any interface.

Below is my rt_tables

```
root@poweredge:/etc/iproute2# cat rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
10 wlx74da388c32d0
11 wlx74da388c32c7
```

and below is my `ip a` command after setting the static ip on the wlx74da388c32c7 interface

```
root@poweredge:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:4f:cd:c1:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.212/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21e:4fff:fecd:c15f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlx74da388c32c7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:da:38:8c:32:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.100/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global wlx74da388c32c7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlx74da388c32d0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:da:38:8c:32:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.11.107/24 brd 172.16.11.255 scope global wlx74da388c32d0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My `ip route list` when DHCP is being used

```
root@poweredge:~# ip route list
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 onlink 
172.16.11.0/24 dev wlx74da388c32d0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.11.107 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.212 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlx74da388c32c7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.209
```

My `ip rule list` when DHCP is being used

```
root@poweredge:~# ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from 192.168.43.209 lookup wlx74da388c32c7 
32765:  from 172.16.11.107 lookup wlx74da388c32d0 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @HaukeLaging should I do those when the static ip is set or when DHCP is set?

Comment: Your `ip a` output shows that the WLAN interfaces are both *down*...

Comment: @HaukeLaging that happens when I set the static ip

Comment: So is the problem gone after `ip link set up dev wlx74da388c32c7; ip link set up dev wlx74da388c32d0`?

Answer (score 0):

in your ouput for **ip rule list** you have the ip *192.168.43.209* this ip does not match with *192.168.43.100* .

To simplify your routing table , you can change  to :

```
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.43.0/24 lookup wlx74da388c32c7
```